# Automate buying via online shop - kolekcjoner.nbp.pl

Tags: python, powershell

I am looking for a way to automate buying coins in online shop kolekcjoner.nbp.pl. They release coins at specific days which are known in advance. There is limited amout of them and you can buy e.g. max 2 coins per person. The problem is that when they add new coin for selling that day (they do it 8 AM specific day) website is very slow, even not responding. So when I am clicking manually in web browser I am not always able to buy coins. I logged on to my account in website before 8 AM of course to not loose time for loggin later

I tried to use some powershell code but struggle with HTML code of this online shop

Comment: This is a very broad question and will most likely not get you any answers. Be more specific in your question (share code, errors, etc.). Also find out if the website has an API to call, that might give you more options and/or control over the process of automating this.

Comment: How to verify if website has API to call?

Comment: By advanced usage of a platform called google search. Also, you deleted your code for some reason. If it's relevant then please leave it in.